# How to focus on an opened background popup in Tridion JS Framework (Anguilla)?

Tags: cme

I have 2 buttons, each opening its own popup. When both popups are opened and the user clicks on the button for the popup in background, I want to focus on that one. The code for each popup is in a separate file (ExportCommand.js and ImportCommand.js). Relevant code bellow:

```
var c = this.properties;
if (c.popupImport && c.popupImport.isOpen()) {
    c.popupImport.focus();
    return;
}

var options = {
        popupType: $popup.Type.SE_MODAL_IFRAME,
        parentNode: view.getMainContentArea(),
        overlayParentNode: view.getLayoutWrapper(),
        pageId: pageId,
        publicationId: publicationId
    };

c.popupImport = $popup.create(url, features, options);
c.popupImport.open();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I control the way popups are created by $popup.create?](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4883/can-i-control-the-way-popups-are-created-by-popup-create)

Comment: I don't know if it is a problem of cache, but if you have defined both popups with diferent names, that solution must work. I have tried and it works for me. Try changing the popup options.

Comment: Is the issue happening when one of the popups is already opened and you *re*select it? If this is the case you probable need to add the c.popupImport.focus() JS to force it back into the forefront.